# QT5 find MySQL but not load it on Debian

Tags: mysql, qt, debian, driver, qt5

(Sorry for my bad english)

My config : Debian 7 / Qt 5
I have a mad problem :

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

So i have do lot of search, but i can't find the bug.

More informations :

```
$ ldd myProg
...
libmysqlclient.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18 (0x00007f0e9f06f000)

$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff67dff000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0033680000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f0033469000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0033264000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f003305c000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0032d55000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0032a56000)
```

In my myProg.pro, i inform `LIBS += -lmysqlclient_r`

Somebody know this problem ?

Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Qt try to load QMYSQL not MySQL.
QMYSQL is provided by Qt (it look like you haven't it.)
As you are French take a look at that: http://fr.openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/qt-et-qmysql-69955

For non-French users google 'QMYSQL Qt' on google you will find a way to install it.